# Как вывести города с определеным средним возрастом?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Доброго дня!
нужно посчитать средний возраст `avg(age)` и вывести города в которых `avg(age) > 40`

так как столбца с возрастом и средним возрастом у меня нет, но есть столбец `BirthDay`
я считаю возраст и средний возраст следующим образом :
     `select city, avg(age) as AverageAge from (select city,DATEDIFF (YY, BirthDate, GETDATE()) -CASE
    WHEN DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY, birthdate, GETDATE()), birthdate)`
    `> GETDATE() THEN 1
    ELSE 0`
`END AS [age] 
from Employees) x group by city`

Тим образом выводятся все города и средний возраст в них, подскажите пожалуйста как задать условие `where averageage > 40`

Comment: пишите это условие в `HAVING`

Comment: @Mike спасибо!!

Answer (score 0):

```
select city, avg(age) as averageAge
from (select city, firstname, lastname, DATEDIFF (YY, BirthDate, GETDATE()) -
    CASE
     WHEN DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY, birthdate, GETDATE()), birthdate)
     > GETDATE() THEN 1
   ELSE 0
END AS [age] 
from Employees) X group by city HAVING(avg(age)) > 60
```

всего-то нужно было добавить HAVING(avg(age)) > 60 как посоветовал @Mike

Comment: отметьте ответ как правильный